# Childwindow + Custom Textbox binding problems

Tags: c#, silverlight, custom-controls, bindingsource, childwindow

Greetings everyone,

I'm having a very strange problem. 
I've created a DateTextBox which automaticly adds the dashes when typing a Date or when you typ something like 1-1-1986 it automaticly makes it 01-01-1986 (while typing).

In this control I validate the date and then update the binding source using

```
this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

this works properly in any form but when I start using it in a childwindow it does get to the `this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();`

but it doesn't update the source.
Any breakpoint at the "set" will be ignored.

Even when element binding it to a datepicker it still doesn't update when I typ in a valid date.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

[edit 1]
Forgot to add that this control and stuff is in silverlight. But I assume people would have guessed that
[/edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this with several extra properties.